# String to variable conversion

Tags: python

I enter the following:

```
>>> a=2
>>> x0=1
>>> b='a*x0'
```

Now I want the value of `b`, which is `a*x0`, i.e., `b=2*1=2`. How to implement this code?

Comment: `'b={0}*{1}={2}'.format(a, x0, a*x0)`

Comment: b=a*x0 remover quote

Comment: @RottenCandy why do you think that eval is required? see my previous comment...

Comment: @alfasin i think he first wants to store the string separately and then evaluate it.

Comment: @RottenCandy and both can be done without using `eval` :)